# Google Api Exception 10, 16, 1500, 1502

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, google-signin, google-developers-console

I have just published new version of my application on GooglePlay Store. Previous version was uploaded 3 months ago. I did not change keystore for signin application. I am also NOT using Firebase for authentication (just for push notifications).

Application just get approved but there is no possibility to login by Google.
I have logs from the devices and there are different errors on login screen.
All of the error are logging the same exception:

```
Java.lang.Throwable: Google API Exception 16:
```

However the detailed messages are different:

- Google API Exception 10:
- Google API Exception 12500:
- Google API Exception 12502:
- Google API Exception 12501:

I have seen the common problem is about SHA1 compatibility or passing correct client id in method .requestIdToken(getString(CLIENT_ID)

I have checked that on Google Play Console -> App signing my SHA1 EQUALS to the SHA1 on Google Console for Credetnails Android.
Also my CLIENT_ID also existss as Web Application

I literally did not change anything related with authentication it just stopped to work with above exception after publish to Google Play.